# -su: syntax error near unexpected token `<' when edit mapred-site.xml

Tags: linux, hadoop, ubuntu-14.04

```html
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
    <value>local</value>
  </property>
  </configuration>
```

Hi,

I am trying to edit the mapred-site.xml file with below configuration entries but keep receiving an error: -su: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Thank you for your help, Michal.

Comment: It seems clear what you are missing

Comment: I still don't  know what I am missing, It's the first time I set up Hadoop on Ubuntu

Comment: Which command do you execute when getting this error?

Comment: <configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name>
    <value>local</value>
  </property>
  </configuration>

Comment: This is the content of mapred-site.xml. I asked what is the command you run that gives you the error: **error: -su: syntax error near unexpected token `<'**

Comment: I am trying to edit the mapred-site.xml file and entered the above configuration. The command is above (content)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to run the following section on your linux shell:

```
<configuration> <property> <name>mapreduce.jobtracker.address</name> <value>local</value> </property> </configuration>
```

which gives you the error: **bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'**.

To edit a file in linux, you can use the **nano** text editor.
If you don't have it installed you can install it by:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nano
```

After that, open the `mapred-site.xml` file like that:

`sudo nano /path/to/mapred-site.xml`

Edit the text you want, and then click `Ctrl + O` => click `Enter` and then click `Ctrl + X` to exit the text editor.

Comment: This is great answer, Thank you for your help!